# Виснет ие при использование яндекс карты более 600 меток

Tags: javascript, яндекс-карты

Подвисают браузера при отрисовке объектов на яндекс карте, объединили их в кластера, но  Internet Explorer виснет само страшно. Что можно сделать?
Вот страница http://p2.nita-farm.ru/where-to-buy/krs/

Comment: Ваше "ие", надеюсь, не расшифровывается как Internet Explorer?

Comment: Да именно про него речь

Comment: И зачем Вам ie? Там все будет виснуть

Answer (score 0):

Можно взглянуть на пример загрузки данных для балуна метки по требованию: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_manager_balloon_async